# Highlighting a specific country on a world map

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet to display a list of country names in a side panel. I am also showing them highlighted on a world map.

When I click on a name in the side panel, I want to change the color of the associated country on the map.

Here is a snippet of my code:

**DISPLAY LIST OF COUNTRY NAMES IN SIDE PANEL**

```
$('#sidecol').empty();
$('#sidecol').html(COUNTRIES)  
for (i=0; i < featureCollection.features.length; i++){
    //console.log(featureCollection.features[i].properties.NAME);  
    $('#sidecol').append("div class = cntrys id = cntry_" + i + 'center><p class="title"><a href = #>' + featureCollection.features[i].properties.NAME + '/a>/center>br>')  
cntryIds.push(featureCollection.features[i].id) //country id  
}
```

**COLOR FILL FOR COUNTRY CHOSEN**

```
function getColor(d) {  
cntryIds.forEach(function(value){  
    //alert('index: ' + index);  
    alert('D is ' + d);  
    alert(value);  
    return d == value ? 'green' :  
                        'orange';  
    });  
}
```

**STYLE FUNCTION CALLED WHEN COUNTRY NAME IS CLICKED ON IN SIDE PANEL**

```
function newstyle(value) {
    //alert('1 ' + value);
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(value),
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}
```

**CLICK EVENT OF COUNTRY NAME IN SIDE PANEL**

```
$(".cntrys").each(function(index, value) { 
  //console.log('cntrys' + index + ': ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' xxx:  ' + cntryIds[index]); 
    $(this).click(function(){
        //alert($(this).attr('id') + " country id: " + cntryIds[index]);
        countries = L.geoJson(featureCollection, 
        {
            style: newstyle(cntryIds[index]),
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature 
        }).addTo(map);
        //console.log(getData());
        map.fitBounds(countries.getBounds().pad(0.5));
    });
});
```

I am trying to change the fillColor option in the newstyle function via the getColor function. Any assistance or suggestion is greatly associated...

Comment: For such programming questions, you may have quicker support on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ghybs Can I move the question to SO or do I re-ask it?

Comment: If the below answer does not work for you, feel free to move it to SO. If you cannot, simply re-ask on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The way you implement the "click" event, as well as the `newstyle` and `getColor` functions look much more complicated than necessary.

It seems to me that your `getColor` function does not return any value: it executes an anonymous function for each item in `cntryIds` array. That anonymous function *does return* a value, but it is not used within `getColor`, which does not return anything in the end. Therefore the `fillColor` property is `undefined` in the style object returned by your `newstyle` function.

Furthermore, you add your entire `featureCollection` as a new GeoJSON layer on each country name click.

Demo of the country layer highlighting functionality when its name is clicked in a list: http://plnkr.co/edit/PNsZc9JxXuzhxTAn6LgC?p=preview

The main part of that code (using jQuery like you seem to do):

```js
$('#sidecol').empty();
var myGeojSonLayerGroup = L.geoJson(world, {
  onEachFeature: myOnEachFeature,
  style: myStyle
}).addTo(map);

$(".cntrys").click(function() {
  var item = $(this);
  console.log("clicked on item " + item.data("countryName"));
  myGeojSonLayerGroup.resetStyle(myGeojSonLayerGroup);
  item.data("countryLayer").setStyle({
    fillColor: "red",
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
  });
});

function myOnEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  var name = feature.properties.NAME;
  var item = $('<div class="cntrys"><p class="title">' + name + '</p></div>');
  item.data("countryLayer", layer);
  item.data("countryName", name);
  $('#sidecol').append(item);
}
```

Of course you could change the styling and even have a specific colour per country.